# Form Display: How to move elements out of the advanced container?

Tags: 8, entities

I want to tweak the *node add/edit form* for one of my content-types and rearrange the fields in different groups.

I use the [Field Group Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) to setup the different groups.

On the *Manage Form Display* settings of the content-type I rearrange the Fields, which works fine for all fields but "Authored by", "Promoted to front page" and so on. All this fields are rendered in an "advanced" container, no matter what.

This is also part of the classy theme file [node-edit-form.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!themes!classy!templates!content-edit!node-edit-form.html.twig/8)

```
  <div class="layout-region layout-region-node-main">
    {{ form|without('advanced', 'actions') }}
  </div>
  <div class="layout-region layout-region-node-secondary">
    {{ form.advanced }}
  </div>
```

Is there any way to break this up, so I can move the containing fields into different groups, just like any other field?

Comment: Dunno but just FYI those fields are Extra fields, not Field API fields so there might be some limitations in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These Fields are organized in different groups in [NodeForm::form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!NodeForm.php/function/NodeForm%3A%3Aform/8).

So the settings from *Manage Form Display* wont work until the `#group` property of the fields is unset or the surrounding container is unset.

This can be done with one of the *form alter hooks* in your theme or custom module.

For example the [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/8):

```
function your_theme_form_node_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    unset($form['author']);
}
```

This will unset the author container. The containing fields *Authored on* and *Authored by* can than be moved around with the *Manage Form Display* Form.