# Form display: How to move fields into the advanced group?

Tags: 8, forms

How can I move a field in a node edit form from the main region into the advanced/secondary group region in the right-hand column?

This [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/248490/27135) asks how to move elements out of the secondary group into the main group, but this is the inverse.

I tried setting a group for my field in a similar way to the above answer:

```
$form['field_article_language_filter']['#group'] = 'advanced';
```

This did move it, but I'd like it to be in a group with a summary arrow button to toggle it closed or open.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a custom module or your theme, create a group and place your field in there:

```
/*
* Implements hook_form_alter()
* @param     Array $form, Object $form_state, Array $form_id
* @return    Array $form
*/
function MY_MODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state,  $form_id) {

  // Create a languages group in the right-hand column
  $form['languages'] = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => t('Languages'),
    '#group' => 'advanced',
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => ['node-form-options']
    ],
    '#attached' => [
      'library' => ['node/drupal.node'],
    ],
    '#weight' => 100,
    '#optional' => TRUE,
    '#open' => TRUE,
  ];

  // Move the languages settings to the right-hand column
  $form['field_article_language_filter']['#group'] = 'languages';

  return $form;
}
```

This is based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/zerolab/39b65abef5ff42e6844072f0ac6f5750), thanks to Dan Braghis.

Comment: This works fine, thanks. FWIW, there is also an issue for the field group module, hopefully this gets fixed someday: https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group/issues/2652642